# Setting verbose to 0 doesn't work as expected

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning

I have developed a Deep Q-Learning agent. I have used `verbose=0` in `model.fit()` function and still getting the following line as output:

```
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 12ms/step
```

here's how i build the model:

```
def build_model(self):
    # Build the model
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(24, input_dim=STATE_SIZE, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(24, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(ACTION_SIZE, activation='linear'))
    model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer=Adam(lr=self.learning_rate))
    #if os.path.isfile(self.weight_backup):
    #    model.load_weights(self.weight_backup)
    #    self.epsilon = self.epsilon_min
    return model
```

I fit the data in replay() function:

```
def replay(self, batch_size):
    # training
    if len(self.memory) < batch_size:
        return
    mini_batch = random.sample(self.memory, batch_size)
    for state, action, reward, next_state, done in mini_batch:
        if done:
            target = reward
        else:
            target = reward + self.gamma * np.amax(self.model.predict(next_state)[0])
        train_target = self.model.predict(state)
        train_target[0][action] = target
        #callbacks = [ProgbarLogger()]
        self.model.fit(state, train_target, epochs=1, verbose=0)
```

Is there a way to prevent output?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution. It comes from `predict()` function and after setting verbose to 0 fixed the problem